# Nedarim-Shevuot Tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I am curios why the nedarim-shevuot tag is a [single tag.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nedarim-shevuot)

The Mishnah separates them into separate categories.

Answer (score 6):

The Mishna also puts Lulav and Sukkah in the same tractate even though we have them as separate tags. We aren't modelling the Mishna here. We're making useful groupings to help people find things on our site.

If there become enough different questions to make separate Neder and Shevuot tags useful, we can split it up. For now I don't see much benefit in doing so.

Comment: I bring that as an example, but it is only a misconception that they should be used interchangeably.

Comment: @shmuel no one is advocating using the two terms interchangeably

Comment: would it help to call it nedarim-and-shevuot ? seems to answer both of yours and the OP concerns

Comment: @Shmuel Most helpful would be to [write a tag wiki](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/1863).